# Pass variables to jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

so simple question! How can I pass a variable into a jQuery function, like in Javascript?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   function foo(bar) {
     $("#content").load(bar);
    }
    </script>
    <a href="#" onClick="foo('test.php');">Load</a>
```

The above code doesn't work, clearly, but hopefully you can get an idea for what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *are* programming in JavaScript.
jQuery is just a library - a bunch of JavaScript functions you can use; it is not another language.

That said, a more modern way of achieving your goal is to use jQuery for event binding

```
<a href="#" id="LoadLink">Load</a>
```

.

```
function foo(bar) {
   $("#content").load(bar);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#LoadLink").click(function(){
    foo("test.php");
    return false; //link won't scroll to the top
  }); //click
});//ready
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wtL88/

Comment: I know that, I guess I worded that wrong. And I actually just got it to work right now. But because I like your answer...

Comment: @Jon - Well, you'll be surprised how many programmers don't know that jQuery isn't its own language... Anyway, thanks, and good to hear you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:foo('test.php');">Load</a>
```